# Get specific values of a struct/List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, struct

I'm creating a game in Unity3D + C#.

What I've got at the moment: an SQL datatable, consisting of 8 columns holding a total of 3 entries and a list "_WeapList" that holds every entry (as shown below).

```
public struct data
{
    public string Name;
    public int ID, dmg, range, magazin, startammo;
    public float tbtwb, rltimer;
}

List<data> _WeapList;
public Dictionary<int, data>_WeapoList; //probable change    

[...]

//reading the SQL Table + parse it into a new List-entry
while (rdr.Read())
    {
        data itm = new data();

        itm.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
        itm.ID = int.Parse (rdr["ID"].ToString());
        itm.dmg = int.Parse (rdr["dmg"].ToString());
        itm.range = int.Parse (rdr["range"].ToString());
        itm.magazin = int.Parse (rdr["magazin"].ToString());
        itm.startammo = int.Parse (rdr["startammo"].ToString());
        itm.tbtwb = float.Parse(rdr["tbtwb"].ToString());
        itm.rltimer = float.Parse(rdr["rltimer"].ToString());

        _WeapList.Add(itm);
        _WeapoList.Add(itm.ID, itm);//probable change
    }
```

Now I want to create a "Weapon"-Class that will have the same 8 fields, feeding them via a given ID

How do I extract the values of a specific item (determined by the int ID, which is always unique) in the list/struct?

```
public class Weapons : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public string _Name;
    public int _ID, _dmg, _range, _magazin, _startammo;
    public float _tbtwb, _rltimer;

    void Start()
    {//Heres the main problem
        _Name = _WeapoList...?
        _dmg = _WeapoList...?
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to be doing these lookups often, why not use a Dictionary instead of a List? Something like `Dictionary<int, data> _WeapList`, with the index being the ID of the weapon. Then you can just access it with `_WeapList[weaponID]`, and it'll be a lot quicker than using a loop/LINQ to search through a List.

Comment: You probably want to rethink using a mutable struct.  I'd suggest either making it a class (with properties instead of public fields) or make the struct immutable by adding a constructor that sets private fields and exposes read only properties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: First of all: thank you, I've never used LINQ expressions before, despite that I will also rethink about the struct issue. Nevertheless I do not unterstand how to feed the dictionary, neither do I know how to find for example int dmg of weapon with ID "3". I've created a dictionary and put this "_WeapoList.Add(itm.ID, itm);" into the while(rdr.Read()){ ... }. How would I parse the "dmg" value to my weapon class? dmg = database._WeapList[ ??? ] (I've put these changes into the code above)

Comment: @Csharpest You get back a `data` object from `_WeapList[weaponID]`. So to access any members of it, just use the `.` syntax, eg. `_WeapList[weaponID].dmg`.

Comment: @Serlite Why not put answer for that?

Comment: @Programmer I wanted to first ascertain that the OP wasn't opposed to using a Dictionary for some reason - since it sounds like he's considering it, I think I will put it as answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your collection of weapons may become quite large or you need to frequently look up weapons in it, I would suggest using a Dictionary instead of a List for this (using the weapon ID as the key). A lookup [will be much quicker using a Dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977694/c-sharp-why-is-dictionary-so-much-faster-than-list) than searching through a List using a loop or LINQ.

You can do this by modifying your code to do this as follows:

```
public Dictionary<int, data>_WeapList;

[...]

//reading the SQL Table + parse it into a new List-entry
while (rdr.Read())
{
    data itm = new data();

    itm.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
    itm.ID = int.Parse (rdr["ID"].ToString());
    itm.dmg = int.Parse (rdr["dmg"].ToString());
    itm.range = int.Parse (rdr["range"].ToString());
    itm.magazin = int.Parse (rdr["magazin"].ToString());
    itm.startammo = int.Parse (rdr["startammo"].ToString());
    itm.tbtwb = float.Parse(rdr["tbtwb"].ToString());
    itm.rltimer = float.Parse(rdr["rltimer"].ToString());

    _WeapList.Add(itm.ID, itm);//probable change
}
```

Then, to access elements on the list, just use the syntax:

```
_WeapList[weaponID].dmg; // To access the damage of the weapon with the given weaponID
```

**Guarding against invalid IDs:**

If there's a risk of the `weaponID` supplied not existing, you can use the [`.ContainsKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) method to check for it first before trying to access its members:

```
if (_WeapList.ContainsKey(weaponID))
{
    // Retrieve the weapon and access its members
}
else
{
    // Weapon doesn't exist, default behaviour
}
```

Alternatively, if you're comfortable using `out` arguments, you can use [`.TryGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) instead for validation - this is even quicker than calling `.ContainsKey()` separately:

```
data weaponData;
if (_WeapList.TryGetValue(weaponID, out weaponData))
{
    // weaponData is now populated with the weapon and you can access members on it
}
else
{
    // Weapon doesn't exist, default behaviour
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Do you get exception if the ID does not exist?

Comment: @Programmer Yeah - I'll add a note on how to guard against that, if the OP needs to worry about that.

Comment: Ok. I said that because OP sounds like he's new. I think TryGetValue should do it.

Comment: @Programmer Ah, I'll mention that one as well - was a little uncertain whether using an `out` value might confuse the OP, but I suppose it should be mentioned for completeness' sake...

Comment: It might but OP can google it. @OP  Dictionary is appropriate for this since there will be many data from the database. Using linq or for loop will be a-lot slower than Dictionary.

Comment: Wonderful! This completely sealed the deal! I'm really thankful, it works flawlessly so far! I'm also thankful for the ".TryGetValue" advice, I'll include it, too.

Answer (score 2):

Let `specificWeapon` be a weapon to be searched in the list, then you can use the following code to select that item from the list of weapons, if it is not found then `null`will be returned.  Hope that this what you are looking for:

```
var selectedWeapon =  WeapList.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.ID == specificWeapon.ID);
if(selectedWeapon != null)
{
    // this is your weapon proceed
}
else
{
   // not found your weapon
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ` to search specific object through weaponId

```
var Weapon =  _WeapList.FirstOrDefault(w=> w.ID == weaponId);
```